# npm packs node_modules in random subdirectory

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-publish, npm-pack

I am working on [a project](https://github.com/wathhr/create-theme) that requires me to have `package.json` files in subdirectories with their own `node_modules` folders (kind of like a monorepo).

When I run `npm pack` to see what gets published I see a seemingly random `node_modules` folder get bundled when no other `node_modules` folder gets bundled.

To reproduce:

1. `git clone https://github.com/wathhr/create-theme`
2. Install deps in all required subdirectories (or run the `updateDeps` script)
3. `npm pack`
4. Look at the .tgz file, no directory will have the `node_modules` folder other than `templates/languages/css`

I have tried adding `"bundleDependencies": false` to my `package.json` (as mentioned [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/folders#publishing)) to no avail.